# Calling a php file from a javascript file in wordpress

Tags: customization, ajax

I have a simple pop up form code written in javascript. It is in js/script.js folder inside themes folder.

I am using jquery ajax method to communicate with a php file to store data in db.

The php file is in themes folder. Also i would like to use the wordpress functions in that php file.

The display of pop up and form works fine. But when i submit it, i get 404 error. I am confused as to how to tell wordpress to include this php file.

THanks

---

**EDIT: I could make the jquery code work by giving the full URL to the php file. However, now i want to be able to use the wp functins in that php file.**

Comment: Using WP functions from your own PHP file is a different question - so ask it separately. Also, do a search here, there have been plenty of questions about how to include WP functions in separate PHP files.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to able to use the WordPress functions the your ajax call should be to the wp-admin/admin-ajax.php and you should use `wp_ajax` hook,

take a look at [What's the preferred method of writing AJAX-enabled plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins/9236#9236) I posted a nice example of how to do that there.