# how to get context information inside my funcion

Tags: plugin-development, functions, ajax

What processing is done by wordpress when a page is accessed that loads all contextual information into $post and other variables? and is it possible to trigger this process manually (or simulate it) so function calls have this context?

The reason I'm asking is because I have written a small [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajaxize/) that allows users to call wordpress functions via Ajax.

The plugin works great with context-less functions. It has a big limitation however: calling a function via ajax loses the context information (e.g. $post) that the called function would otherwise have, had it been placed from within a template.

However, the ajax call does send across the HTTP Referrer information. I can easily extract the referrer info, so I know e.g. on which page the user is on. The problem is I'm not sure how to use it further. Any tips/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you're requesting *index.php* which I guess it's the homepage; if I call for example is_category() trough your ajax from the category page I'll get false because the function is being ran on the homepage. Use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` instead (don't forget to sanitize it)
- you're hooking your handler on the `init` action, which I think runs before the post data is set up. Use a different one, like `wp` or `template_redirect`

Comment: Great stuff. Still need to put it all together, but definitely looks like this is the direction I need to take. I'm thinking of using javascript instead of $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] though to pick the right target url. Then the hook change really makes the difference! I have to admit I'm still not particularly clear about processing order / hook points etc in wordpress. Thanks One Trick Pony!

Answer (score 0):

To use WordPress functions from ajax call you need to hook your own function to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

to get a better understanding take a look at [**This**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins/9236#9236).

Comment: That's almost the same as what he's currently doing. He wants those functions to be aware of the current page context, `admin-ajax.php` doesn't accomplish that

Comment: you can always send the current page context with your ajax post

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: sure, on what? on sending the context, say you are on a page you can add to your ajax call something like `context: 'page'` then in your ajax function you can see that the context is a page

Comment: Oh, but that's not what the plugin does. It attempts to generalise ajax calls to ANY function, and the function grabs whichever context it needs. I can't force all functions to know about this context variable... The ajaxize plugin simply wraps around other functions... Thanks though. Looks like I'll stick to One Trick Pony's solution