# External page integrated into WordPress returns a 404 error

Tags: 404-error, headers

I have a script that I'd like to call via AJAX from my WordPress theme, it relies upon some core WordPress functions so I am including WordPress blog header like so:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( '../../../../wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Somewhere during the processing of `wp-blog-header.php` WordPress sets a 404 header which causes my AJAX request to fail, even though the script I am calling exists and is returning content.

I have since added `status_header( 200 );` after that snippet which changes the status header back to 200 and solves the problem, however it feels very much like a hack, so I was just wondering if there is a *recommended* solution to this problem?

Comment: I think you get a 404 header internally, because WP_Query tries to resolve the requested page which it can't. I would look for some flag/const/trick to make WP_Query not execute / overload so to not needlessly burn resources for nothing.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable solution.  I encountered the same problem in a different guise -- when sharing some code between a php application and a closely related WordPress site.  PHP would generate a spurious 404 status code.  Most browsers would ignore 404 status if content was returned; however, IE will sometimes fail to render the page if its "friendly HTTP error message" option is set.  Setting status_header('200') after requiring wp-blog-header.php solved it.

Comment: It sounds like a poorly designed architecture. The script is outside of WordPress, but depends on internal WordPress functions? Is the script on the same server as the WordPress installation? If so, why not just put it in a plugin? If not, it should include [BackPress](http://backpress.org/). What is it using the WP functions for? Maybe your theme should pass it all of the data it needs, so that it doesn't have to use the WP functions.

Comment: This is a maintenance nightmare, using the WP AJAX hooks is much, much simpler and easier, far less effort

Comment: What is this external PHP app you're calling WP from?

Answer (score 4):

You should be including `wp-load.php`, not `wp-blog-header.php` (which is reserved for use by WordPress only). This is most likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: thx! some tutorials say to include wp-blog-header.php .. that was the problem

Comment: Live-saver. Thanks a lot, @shea!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a recommend solution for using WordPress Function via AJAX and that is using the  `wp_ajax` hooks. you can see a very detailed example [**in my answer to "What's the preferred method of writing AJAX-enabled plugins?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins/9236#9236)"

Comment: Thanks for your interesting reply, but that's not the problem I'm having. I'm calling a script external to the WordPress core that needs to include WordPress functionality, however during this process WordPress decides to set a 404 header. Sorry if my question wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including WordPress inside of 'Solution A', have you considered doing it the other way around, using the vastly superior/easier WP AJAX API and then including 'Solution A' inside WordPress?

Calling in wp-blog-header.php for AJAX is a massive mistake, I can't stress how big a headache you're introducing, security and maintenance wise ( e.g. this question demonstrates some of that )

[What's the preferred method of writing AJAX-enabled plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins/9236#9236)

Also include `wp-load.php` not `wp-blog-header.php`