# AJAX wp-mysql running too slow

Tags: database, ajax, wpdb

I have made a function of ajax, which returns all the posts starting with a particular alphabet, suppose a user clicks on letter A, then all the posts starting with letter A will be displayed, any how I am successful in making this function run, but only if I use normal mysql, but I want to use wp-mysql,

My code shall speak for me ;)

```
echo $_GET['letter'];
$getLetter = $_GET['letter'];
global $wpdb;
global $post;

$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_title LIKE "'.$getLetter.'%" AND post_status = "publish" AND post_type="post"');
while($row = $result)
{
  echo '<a href="' . $row["guid"] . '">' . $row['post_title'] . '</a><br>';
}
```

I am using this code which is getting a letter through URL and searching it for in database, but if I use the above code, it takes too long to search for a post(it takes more then a minute), but if I use the below code

```
echo $_GET['letter'];
$getLetter = $_GET['letter'];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db("wordpress", $con);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_title LIKE "'.$getLetter.'%" AND post_status = "publish" AND post_type="post"');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '<a href="' . $row["guid"] . '">' . $row['post_title'] . '</a><br>';
}
```

then everything works quickly,

Can anyone explain me this? I don't know wp-db that much, but I want this to be worked in wpdb

Am I doing something wrong?

EDITED
AJAX CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Loading").hide();
        $(".letter").bind('click', function(){
        $("#Loading").fadeIn(); //show when submitting
        var val = $(".letter").val;
        $.ajax({
             url:'<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/newContent.php?letter='+$(this).html(), 

             success:function(data){
                $("#Loading").fadeOut('fast'); //hide when data's ready
                $("#content1").html(data);
             }
        });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using WordPress AJAX API?

Comment: @Ashfame no, I am using different ajax, but that works perfect, cause when I use normal mysql the ajax works and also when I use the wp-mysql the ajax works but the database takes too long to call

Comment: Try doing it with WordPress AJAX API to figure out if its an issue with your approach or something with WordPress at the moment. Also test it without any plugins, and for once, also check the queries & time taken to generate the page.

Comment: @Ashfame I didn't get you, with wordpress AJAX API?

Just check my question I have updated it with my ajax code, can you explain me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the database directly rather then using the `$wpdb` object its faster for a simple reason which is you only call the database, and the when you use `$wpdb` it loads extra functions and basically most of WordPress before you can use the `$wpdb` object.

What you should try is to use the WordPress Ajax api (not really an api but the right way to use ajax with WordPress). Basically you need to wrap your code in a function and make sure you die at the end:

```
function my_ajax_callback(){
    $getLetter = $_GET['letter'];
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_title LIKE "'.$getLetter.'%" AND post_status = "publish" AND post_type="post"');
    while($row = $result)
    {
      echo '<a href="' . $row["guid"] . '">' . $row['post_title'] . '</a><br>';
    }
    die();
}
```

then you need add an action hook:

```
//if you want only logged in users to access this function use this hook
add_action('wp_ajax_ACTION_NAME', 'my_AJAX_processing_function');

//if you want none logged in users to access this function use this hook
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ACTION_NAME', 'my_AJAX_processing_function');
```

*if you want logged in users and guests to access your function by ajax the add both hooks. *ACTION_NAME must match the action value in your ajax POST.

then just direct the ajax call to admin-ajax.php and add the ACTION_NAME:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Loading").hide();
        $(".letter").bind('click', function(){
            $("#Loading").fadeIn(); //show when submitting
            var val = $(".letter").val;
            var data = {action: 'ACTION_NAME', letter: val};
            $.ajax({
                 url:'url to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                 success:function(data){
                    $("#Loading").fadeOut('fast'); //hide when data's ready
                    $("#content1").html(data);
                 }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

this way it won't load all of WordPress just for that ajax call.

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: But still loading WordPress in a php file doesn't justify the 1 minute time to serve that ajax call. I agree it will be slower but not this much :P

Comment: 1 minute load time simply means that something is badly wrong.

Comment: @Bainternet You're starting to emerge to a AJAX prof. Maybe you could add a new Q that explains it in detail and we make a community wiki out of it?

Comment: @kaiser: a new Q that explains what? you mean this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins/9236#9236

Comment: I already found and corrected it. But it would be helpful to have more insights: a) How can I interact with the response? b) Where does "whatever" come from, how do I set it? How can I interact with the DOM this way?