# problems with jquery external rss feed integration

Tags: jquery, ajax, rss

Iam using an external file (feed_home.php) wich is loaded with AJAX onclick.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $("#new a").click(function(){

        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel")
        $(".featureline").html("loading...");
        $(".featureline").load(jQuery(this).attr("href"))
        return false;
    });
});
```

> feed_home.php

has the following code to load the amazon rss feed:

```
    <?php
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php');
$feed = 'http://www.amazon.de/rss/new-releases/videogames/';
$rss = fetch_feed($feed); ?><?php 
if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) :
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(3);
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
    if ($rss_items):
        echo "<ul>\n";
        foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) :
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="' . $item->get_permalink() . '">' . $item->get_title() . "</a>\n";
            echo '<p>' . $item->get_description() . "</li>\n";
        endforeach;
        echo "</ul>\n";
    endif;
endif;
?>
```

The problem is, that I'm always getting this error:

```
include(stream.php) [function.include]: 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/is/htdocs/...mywebsite/feed_home.php on line 2
```

Without the Ajax, the Amazon Rss Feed appears. Any idea?
Thank you!

AD

---

Well, I think, I am getting slowly what this means:

But I have no clue how to handle this.

the "feed_home.php" has to have something like a minimal Wordpress surrounding, right?

Has it something to do with

```
// Stop most of WordPress from being loaded if we just want the basics.
if ( SHORTINIT )
    return false;
```

But how can I get it work?

Thank you!

AD

Answer (score 1):

Your stand-alone file doesn’t know the WordPress constants and functions. Use the [native WordPress AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) instead.

See also: [What's the preferred method of writing AJAX-enabled plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/9231/73)

In short: Put all your custom code into a function or a class and hook from your plugin into …

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ACTION_NAME', 'your_function');
```

… and …

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ACTION_NAME', 'your_function');
```

Replace `ACTION_NAME` with something very unique.

Comment: Hi Toscho - thank you for the reply. I think I could need a bit more help. I understand, that the stand-alone file is not working, because all the needed stuff is missing, but I am not sure what to exactly do - even after visiting your links - to integrate this stuff. Would be superb if you could give me another hint. Thank you!

Comment: I don’t know where you got stuck. :) Read through the [highest voted AJAX questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=votes&pagesize=50), there are _many_ good, working examples.

Comment: thanks - I add some code I tried to my question - it's kind of wrong - I am sure. But I really don't understand, where to put the stuff....thx

Comment: Could someone give me a little bit more specific hint? thank you!