# ajax sends data to plugin

Tags: plugins, ajax

I'm trying to send datas via jquery ajax to my plugins class to update a filed in a table and I'm getting the following error

Fatal error: Call to a member function query()

my class looks like

```
class MyClass{

    function __construct(){

        global $wpdb;
        $this->db = $wpdb;
        //add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter_queryvars' );
    }

//Save ajax datas
    public function save_tips($token, $tips){
            $this->db->query(
                $this->db->prepare(
                    "UPDATE wp_competitors SET results= %s, update_time= %d",
                    $tips ,$cur_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),  "WHERE token = $token
                ") // $wpdb->prepare
            ); 

    }
}
```

}

when I send the datas with ajax the entry file is my plugin main file and I fire on with the following code

```
if ($_POST['results']){
    $token = '393a9276ae329e00b3739d2e76e52f3b';
    $tips = json_encode($_POST['results']);
    $save = new Tipspiel();
    $save->save_tips($token, $tips);

    return 'OK';
}
```

it seems like all wordpress funtions are ignored

updating the codes after the feedback from @toscho

I was adding the following in my javascript

```
$j("form#tiepspiel").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // this disables the submit button so the user stays on the page            
        var str = $j(this).serialize();
       //alert(decodeURIComponent(str));
        if ($j('ul#sortables li').size() > 10){

            $j( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
                    height: 140,
                    modal: true
                });
            return;
        }
        var data = {
                action: 'TIPPS',
                     tips: str,
                    _ajax_nonce: "<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'my_ajax_nonce' ); ?>"

            };

        $j.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
            //$j.cookie("tipspiel", "competitor", { expires: 1 });
           $j('form#tiepspiel').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                // Animation complete.
              });
        });              
    });
```

and adding this in my plugins entry file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_TIPPS', 'tipps_processing_function');



function tipps_processing_function(){
    check_ajax_referer('my_ajax_nonce');

    if ($_POST['results']){
        $token = '393a9276ae329e00b3739d2e76e52f3b';
        $tips = json_encode($_POST['results']);
        $save = new Tipspiel();
        $save->save_tips($token, $tips);

        return 'OK';
    }
    //do stuff here
}
```

is not clear how to pass the recived variables to my class

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work. Read [What's the preferred method of writing AJAX-enabled plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins)

Do not try to access you plugin files directly.

Comment: thank you for the feedback I have been trying out and couple of things are not quite clear for me. The jquery seems to work but the function is not getting called. If I update the changed codes could you give me some ideas how to handle? Thanks in advanced