# How to get post object on blog template

Tags: permalinks, pages, blog

I have a big issue on catching attributes from global `$post_object` in a page template file.

I have a `Template Name: Blog Page` which is `template-blog.php`

On that page I use the current page permalink to load more posts using Ajax.

So basically I do Ajax Requests in the same URL, and on `template-blog.php` is a condition if `$_POST['load_more']` is true, if yes than return a portion of posts.

My problem is I cant get the page ID or page permalink using the `$post` variable when this page is set as the Blog Page on WordPress (Settings-Reading-Posts Page).

When the `template-blog.php` is set-up as the posts page, the `$post` variable is the first post which `$wp_query` has on it's post's array.

I hope I was clear enough.

#### Description

On normal page State the Permalink is the Page Permalink:

```
get_header();
$link = get_the_permalink();
```

But when this page is set-up as Posts Page the Permalink is the Permalink of the first posts on $wp_query:

```
get_header();
$link = get_the_permalink();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not post the AJAX request to the page you are viewing, [use the AJAX API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins) instead.

To get the permalink for the *blog* page use:

```
get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
```

Comment: Ok than forget about Ajax, but how can i get the Permalink if i need if page is on that State ?