# POST from jQuery to PHP

Tags: posts, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that passes field values to jQuery, which validates the fields and creates the variables being sent in `data: {}` in the snippet below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/process.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        "title":title,
        "goals":goals,
        "progress":progress,
        "categories":categories,
        "tags":tags,
        "video":video,
        "audio":audio,
    },
    success: function() {
        //get permalink for post from php and go to it
    }
});
```

`process.php` is not receiving any data, or it's not posting the data.

I'm not sure why.

Below is my `process.php` file:

```
<?php

    $user_submitted_title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['user_submitted_title']);
    $user_submitted_progress = $_POST['user_submitted_progress'];
    $user_submitted_goals = $_POST['user_submitted_goals'];
    $user_submitted_categories = $_POST['user_submitted_categories'];
    $user_submitted_tags = sanitize_text_field($_POST['user_submitted_tags']);
    $user_submitted_video = sanitize_text_field($_POST['user_submitted_video']);
    $user_submitted_audio = sanitize_text_field($_POST['user_submitted_audio']);

    $user_post = array(
        'comment_status' => 'open',
        'post_author'    => $user_ID,
        'post_category'  => array($user_submitted_categories),
        'post_content'   => '<h2>Project Progress</h2>' . $user_submitted_progress . '<h2>Project Goals</h2>' . $user_submitted_goals,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_title'     => $user_submitted_title,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'tags_input'     => $user_submitted_tags
    );

    $user_post_id = wp_insert_post($user_post);
    add_post_meta($user_post_id, 'wpcf-video', $user_submitted_video);
    add_post_meta($user_post_id, 'wpcf-audio', $user_submitted_audio);

    $user_post_redirect = get_permalink($user_post_id);

?>
```

I need to figure out why nothing posts when I use the form and how to send `$user_post_redirect` back to jQuery so I can redirect to it.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please read http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins – your method cannot work in WordPress.

Comment: my form is in a page template, my jquery is in a header template, and my php is in a file called process.php. Can that work within those files, or do i have to make a plugin?

Comment: Do what Milo suggested; this is The Way to handle AJAX in WordPress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you load your `process.php` file directly, it's not within the context of the WordPress environment, so no WordPress functions are available. WordPress has a native [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) that should be used for this sort of thing.

First, [enqueue your javascript file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), then use [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass the location of `admin-ajax.php`, which will be processing the requests:

```
function wpa_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'wpa_script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',
        array('jquery'),
        null,
        true
    );
    $script_data = array(
        'admin_ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'wpa_script',
        'wpa_data',
        $script_data
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_scripts' );
```

Next, add an `action` to your ajax data, which will map to the function hooked to process the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: wpa_data.admin_ajax,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        "action":"some_action",
    },
    success: function() {
        //get permalink for post from php and go to it
    }
});
```

Last, add the action in php and hook it to the function which will receive and process it, then move the contents of process.php inside this function

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_some_action', 'your_process_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_some_action', 'your_process_function' );
```

Comment: ok, thank you. where do i put add_action( 'wp_ajax_some_action', 'your_process_function' );

Comment: in your theme's `functions.php` file or a plugin, along with the `your_process_function` that's hooked to the action.

Comment: can i add a nonce by putting _ajax_nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'my_ajax_nonce' ); ?>' in the data array?

Comment: It still isn't posting. can i send you my functions file, my header template, and my page template? I can put them up on pastebin

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. sanitize text field was breaking it, because ajax isnt submitting text fields. i'll sanitize those fields before the ajax call. Thank you so much. can you give me a link to your personal website so i can give you credit in the site i'm making?