# Pass jquery variable to php function and run it

Tags: jquery

This is possible duplicate question but I couldn't make it work with this link "[POST from jQuery to PHP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99724/post-from-jquery-to-php)"
So please help me to achieve this. I am trying to pass jquery variables to php function and run it. I have freshdeskreply.js file and I have my php function in send_reply.php in theme folder.

On js file I am trying to pass this.name (which is ticket id) and textreply (which is textarea value) to my php function and run it. I've been trying to do this for a week already but couldn't make it work, please show it to me step by step. Thank you.

I am also able to alert the js values but can not post them to php function.
js file is already registered and works on page load.

functions.php

```
/*Reply JS*/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );

function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js_library', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/freshdeskreply.js' );
    wp_localize_script( 'my_js_library', 'my_local_var', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
/*END - Reply JS*/
```

freshdeskreply.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
         /*Ticket Reply button*/
      $('[id^="send_reply"]').click(function() {
         var textreply = $('textarea#replyarea' + this.name).val();
            if(!textreply.trim()){
       alert("Reply area can not be empty...");
      }
      else{
        $.ajax({
    url: my_local_var.ajax_url, 
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
      action: 'myaction', 
      textreply: textreply,
      ticketid: this.name
    },
    success: function( data ){
      //Do something with the result from server
      console.log( data );
    }
  });
       alert(textreply);
       alert(this.name);
       location.reload();
        }
      });

});
```

send_reply.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', 'post_note' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'post_note' );

    /*Reply*/
    function post_note() {

                    $api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                    $password = "x";
                    $yourdomain = "XXX";

                    $ticketid = $_POST['ticketid'];
                    $reply_body = $_POST['textreply'];

                    $notprivate = "false";

                    $note_payload = array(
                      'body' => $reply_body,
                      'private' => $notprivate,
                      'user_id' => $contact_id,
                    );

                    $url = "https://$yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets/$ticketid/notes";
                    $ch = curl_init($url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$api_key:$password");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $note_payload);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
                    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
                    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
                    $headers = substr($server_output, 0, $header_size);
                    $response = substr($server_output, $header_size);

                    if($info['http_code'] == 201) {

                    }
                                    curl_close($ch);
    }
    /*End Reply*/
```

Comment: It means refactoring what you've got, but after a week I would recommend investing the time in understanding how WordPress handles Ajax natively.   The benefits far outweigh the drawbacks . https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have already found this one too but still couldn't make it. How am I going to call that specific function?

Comment: Yes I added that hook but still no luck, I can not see where is the problem at

Comment: I edited my current code, above is the most updated one.

Comment: I think it doesn't run the php function

Comment: Are you logged in to WP when testing?  There are two actions for hooking Ajax calls: `wp_ajax_youraction` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_youraction`.  The "nopriv" version is for users that are not logged in and therefore have no privileges.  You need both.  I did not get a chance to look at this last night but I can do so now.

Comment: Yes I am testing it as admin

Comment: Please add your button markup above.

Comment: Ok, I added button code

Comment: I see why your enqueue was failing when hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts`.  That should be done earlier than template load; typically in functions.php.  When you enqueue in the template like you have, that action has already fired.   You are also trying to localize in the wrong place.  Both your enqueue and localization should happen in functions.php, before template loading.

Comment: Thank you, yes you are right, I added the add_action part on functions.php and js started working but still cannot call the send_reply.php

Comment: If you are using Chrome, inside the dev tools panel, click on the Network tab, filter for XHR and reload the page.  You should see your Ajax request, the headers & response, etc.

Comment: I see admin-ajax.php under XHR, when it completes it says 400 under status column

Comment: this is the error -> POST http://***/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Place the code from your send-reply.php into functions.php.  Unless you are including that file to the functions file.  The `add_action()` statements won't register the hooks correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested this locally and found the issues.

When you reg/enq the JS, you need to localize the script.  This is your chance to pass anything from PHP to the script.  In this case, you should, at minimum, pass the WP ajax url like this:

```
    wp_localize_script( 'my_js_library', 'my_local_var', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

More details here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script#Usage

In your JS, update the URL param given to the `ajax()` call to use this value:

```
url: 'send_reply.php', // wrong
url: my_local_var.ajax_url,  // right
```

You should also enqueue your script inside a function hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts`.  You may be doing this and simply didn't past above.  Add this code to functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );

function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js_library', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/freshdeskreply.js' );
    wp_localize_script( 'my_js_library', 'my_local_var', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

NOTE: PHP will not be available for execution unless it has been included (to functions.php, etc) or hooked to an action.  The OP's callback and action hooks were in an external PHP file which was not loaded.

EDIT: fixed code formatting from original post.

EDIT: clarified where to add enqueue and localization code.

EDIT: added note to move ajax actions and callback to functions.php

Comment: When I added `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );` js doesn't work so, I added them `wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js_library', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/freshdeskreply.js' );`
`wp_localize_script( 'my_js_library', 'my_local_var', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );` individually in support-template.php. However, still it doesn't call the send_reply.php

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"?  It's hard to determine a solution from that.  Update the code in question please and I will look at it.

Comment: JS alerts didn't work. I have 3 files support-template.php (includes the button and  js `wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js_library', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/freshdeskreply.js' );`) - freshdeskreply.js (which takes the data from support-template.php) - send_reply.php (this is for to get the data from js and send it to freshdesk.) I also updated the code above

Comment: Is your JS file loading on the page?  You mention the enqueue statement was failing.  Using the `my_scripts()` function above, hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts` on my test machine enqueues the JS OK.

Comment: Yes when I use add_action wp_enqueue_scripts hook js doesn't work, alerts not working. If I add it without the add_action then alerts work