# Ajax calls in wordpress

Tags: posts, functions, ajax

I want to send a ajax request in wordpress which tracks my clicks. For now i have added this in my functions file :

```
add_action('init', 'my_script_enqueuer');

  function my_script_enqueuer() {
    wp_register_script("history_script", get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/history_script.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('history_script', 'myAjax', array('ajaxurl' => get_template_directory_uri().'/functions.php'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('history_script');
  }

  add_action("wp_ajax_history_trace", "history_trace");

  function history_trace() {
      echo 'fasfasgasgas'; die;
}
```

and in my js file :

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

   jQuery("#searchsubmit").click( function() { 
      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {action: "history_trace"},
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
               alert('success')
            }
            else {
               alert("false")
            }
         }
      })   

   })

})
```

But when i see my console the rquest appears in red color and there is no response. Please Help!!

Comment: Read http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins and use the correct AJAX URL.

Comment: Yes i waas trying to use it in functions..thanks..

Answer (score 1):

your ajax url is wrong i think. ajax link should be admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ). That means

```
wp_localize_script('history_script', 'myAjax', array('ajaxurl' => get_template_directory_uri().'/functions.php'));
```

will be this

```
wp_localize_script('history_script', 'myAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ));
```

Comment: Yes it is a misytake