# BBPress AJAX problem

Tags: ajax, bbpress

I am using version 2.1.3 and I need ajax function in user profile.

Problem is that ajax is running fine when the user is "ADMIN" or user with ID 1(my guesses).
When I want to use ajax with another user it just wont work.

Through ajax function I get error 404.

I guess this is something with user permissions... Can someone help me ?

P.S When I installed 2.2 version it working fine. But 2.1.3 has old structure and I need the old one for working.

CODE UPDATE:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="button">Click on IT!</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").live('click', function() {
   var dataString = 'check';
   alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>',
    data: dataString,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
                alert("WORKS");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
        });
});
</script>
```

I noticed that in function bbp_parse_query which is in bbp-template-functions.php, if I change value of $posts_query->is_404  = false; to $posts_query->is_404  = TRUE; it working but I dont know why ...

Comment: the code is working fine it is bbpress problem...

Comment: See [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins) to understand how AJAX works in WordPress. Short story: you are using the wrong AJAX URL.

Comment: But how can you explain this, when I install newer version of bbpress it works without problem ?

Comment: Maybe `check` is a reserved variable on the front page in bbPress? You should really upgrade.

Comment: no i changed in unique and nothing ...

Comment: I need the old version because where are lots of modification. But I am trying with fresh install too and still no luck...