# Different page template for paginated content?

Tags: pagination, infinite-scroll

Sorry for the basic question, but I can't track down a solution (or maybe it's just hard to search for).

I'm creating my own infinite scroll system for a wordpress site I'm working on. For ease of development it would be beneficial for the 'paginated' content to be on a separate template (so that I can just output the content, and ignore the rest of the template). Can this be done in wordpress?

i.e.

`domain.tld/content-page` should use `content-page.php`

`domain.tld/content-page/page/1` should use `content-page-paginated.php`

I suppose the obvious alternative is having logic in content-page.php that checks to see if it's paged content and outputs differently if that's the case.

Comment: Why not use AJAX and return the value without calling a template at all.

Comment: That'd be neat, but often even with ajax you're still calling a template, you're just processing it in javascript - I would be using the above template with ajax, that's it's intended purpose. Can you get the data out of WP in a json object or similar?

Comment: well yes you can, and you don't need a template for that just a callback function, have a look at this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9236/2487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose the obvious alternative is having logic in content-page.php that checks to see if it's paged content and outputs differently if that's the case.

Basically.

In `content-page.php`:

```
get_header();

//WordPress has a global variable for whether a post/page is paginated or not
global $paged; 

// If post/page isn't paginated
if ($paged === 0) {
    //Do stuff that you want for non-paginated posts/pages
}
//If post/page is paginated
else {
    include 'content-page-paginated.php';
}

get_footer();
```

(Edit: changed `$multipage` to `$paged` as per Nathan's comment)

Comment: ```$multipage``` is reporting as NULL whether on the first page or second for me…

Comment: Ah, think I got it. The relevant variable in my case is ```$paged```.

Comment: @Nathan: Sorry about that. I edited the answer for reference in case anyone has the same problem in the future.