# how to get Pretty permalinks($wp_rewrite) till `INIT` action?

Tags: permalinks

i want to call `get_permalink()` in early actions (i.e. `plugins_loaded` or in custom php file, that calls `wp-load.php`), but i get error:

**`Trying to get property of non-object in..`** because get_permalink calls $wp_rewrite, and it is not defined yet (it is generated in `init` ).

how to manually generate `$wp_rewrite` earlier?
i know that `custom_post_type`s are generated in `init`, but i still want it earlier.

Comment: never do anything before `init`, best to use `wp_loaded`.

Comment: Hook into `wp` instead? Unless you badly need `init` then there are few tricks..

Comment: @SamuelElh yes, tell me those tricks, please.

Comment: What is your end goal? If permalinks aren't set up early enough for your code then maybe there's something you should be doing a different way.

Comment: well, i just want an ajax call, that returns only permalink, and that's why i dont want full WP loaded.

Comment: Well you might do better to rewrite your question to explain that, as what you describe doesn't sound like the right (or easiest) approach.  Using AJAX in WP is well defined: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins

Comment: well, forget `ajax`, i just want to get permalink in the earliest wp loading.