# i can't use wordpress functions in ajax loaded php file

Tags: functions, categories, ajax

I want to make a chained select like this
brand > model

for that i make a file named cat.php in my themes folder that contains this code

```
<div id="categories">

    <?php
    $args = array(
        'show_option_none' => __( 'برند را انتخاب کنید' ),
        'orderby'          => 'name',
        'hide_empty'         => 0,
        'tab_index'          => 0,
        'echo'             => 0,
        'parent'           => 0
    );
    ?>

    <?php $select  = wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
    <?php $replace = "<select$1>"; ?>
    <?php $select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select ); ?>

    <?php echo $select; ?>

    <select id="model">
        <option value="">ابتدا برند را انتخاب کنید</option>
    </select>
    <select id="engine">
        <option value="">ابتدا مدل را انتخاب کنید</option>
    </select>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$('#cat').on('change',function(){
    var brandID = $(this).val();
    if(brandID){
        alert("id="+brandID)
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/layouts/blocks/ajaxdata.php',
            data:'brand_id='+brandID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#model').html(html);
                $('#engine').html('<option value="">لطفا ابتدا مدل را انتخاب کنید</option>'); 
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('خطا در بارگذاری اطلاعات');
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#model').html('<option value="">لطفا ابتدا برند را انتخاب کنید</option>');
        $('#engine').html('<option value="">لطفا ابتدا مدل را انتخاب کنید</option>'); 
    }
});
});
</script>
```

in this code when user choose the first select (#cat) it post the id to the ajaxdata.php and it will return all response in secound select with id #model
but when i use wordpress functions inside ajaxdata.php it return nothing and ajax alert the error

ajaxdata.php : 
        `<?php
    if(!empty($_POST["brand_id"])){
        echo '<option>لطفاانتخاب کنید'.$_POST["brand_id"].'</option>';
        $args = array('parent' => $_POST["brand_id"],'hide_empty' => 0);
        $categories = get_categories( $args );
        foreach($categories as $category) { 
            echo '<option>'. $category->name.'</option> ';
        }
    }?>`
how i can fix this problem

---

i changed my codes due the ducumention @fuxia gives me in link.
cats.php file :

```
    <?php
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_AD_CAR_SELECT',                         'my_AJAX_processing_function');
    add_action('wp_ajax_AD_CAR_SELECT', 'my_AJAX_processing_function');
    ?>

    <div id="categories">

    <?php
    $args = array(
        'show_option_none' => __( 'برند را انتخاب کنید' ),
        'orderby'          => 'name',
        'hide_empty'         => 0,
        'tab_index'          => 0,
        'echo'             => 0,
        'parent'           => 0
    );
    ?>

    <?php $select  = wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
    <?php $replace = "<select$1>"; ?>
    <?php $select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select ); ?>

    <?php echo $select; ?>

    <select id="model">
        <option value="">ابتدا برند را انتخاب کنید</option>
    </select>
    <select id="engine">
        <option value="">ابتدا مدل را انتخاب کنید</option>
    </select>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
        $('#cat').on('change',function(){
            var brandID = $(this).val();
            if(brandID){
                alert("id="+brandID)
                var data = {
            action: 'AD_CAR_SELECT',
            brandID: brandID,
            _ajax_nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'my_ajax_nonce' ); ?>'
        };

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('#model').html(response);
            $('#engine').html('<option value="">لطفا ابتدا مدل را انتخاب کنید</option>'); 
        });

    }else{
        $('#model').html('<option value="">لطفا ابتدا برند را انتخاب کنید</option>');
        $('#engine').html('<option value="">لطفا ابتدا مدل را انتخاب کنید</option>'); 
    }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

functions.php file of theme :
                function my_AJAX_processing_function(){
                   check_ajax_referer('my_ajax_nonce');
                   //do stuff here

```
       if(!empty($_POST["brand_id"])){
            echo '<option>لطفاانتخاب کنید'.$_POST["brand_id"].'</option>';
            $args = array('parent' => $_POST["brand_id"],'hide_empty' => 0);
            $categories = get_categories( $args );
            foreach($categories as $category) { 
                echo '<option>'. $category->name.'</option> ';
            }
        }
    }
```

still not worked ... :(

Comment: Do not use a custom PHP file to handle AJAX requests, use the WordPress API instead: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins

Comment: could you help me with my example i cant done it ...

Comment: @fuxia could you help me more?